# How to use an RPM option in a yum upgrade?

Tags: rpm, yum

I need to upgrade an RPM installed via YUM, which has an fatal bug in its postun section.

This will get run (and delete the program's user, which is what I want to not happen) when I run "yum upgrade".

I know that if I were using rpm directly, I could just use the "-nopostun" option to skip this section, but I don't see a way of accessing that option from yum's man page.

Anyone know a way round this?

Comment: Try serverfault.com or your distributions forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answering my own question...)

It looks as though it might be as simple as doing "rpm --erase --nopostun" to remove the bad rpm, and then running "yum install" to reinstall the good new version.

Comment: Your answer is correct because yum does not provide a way to remove a package without running the package's preuninstall and postuninstall scriptlets. Please accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the "yum-tsflags" plugin which can be used, which means you still get history etc. in recent yum ... but it should be so rare it doesn't matter too much.